# sort function in list in python program?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
list1 = { 'aa':4, 'ab':3, 'wr':7, 'de':6 }
```

I need output for this :

```
wr:7
de:6
aa:4
ab:3
```

If I need only 2 lines then how to do like -
we:7
de:6

I don't want use to the import/collection function. I want to try by the for loop. if you any idea please suggest.

Comment: That's not a list, its a dictionary. Please also show us what you've tried rather than asking for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1 = { 'aa':4, 'ab':3, 'wr':7, 'de':6 }
print({k: v for k, v in sorted(list1.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True)})
```

I've used the list comprehension to sort by the values of the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

For numeric values you can sort on the negated values to get decreasing order:

```
list1 = { 'aa':4, 'ab':3, 'wr':7, 'de':6 }

for k,v in sorted(list1.items(),key=lambda kv:-kv[1]):
    print(f"{k}:{v}")

wr:7
de:6
aa:4
ab:3
```

Comment: If I need only 2 lines then how to do like - we:7 \n de:6

Comment: You can slice the result of the sort: `sorted(...)[:2]`